Possible wrong solution
In Proakis' book on DSP (4th Edition) problem 6.3 seems to have an incorrect solution. The problem and its solution are attached below:


The issue is that after the LPF the maximum frequency is 100Hz and the sampling frequency is 200Hz which only just satisfies the Nyquist rate. Since the filter is ideal shouldn't there be no aliasing in this case? Which would be in contradiction of the solution presented which does suggest that there is aliasing.


Since the filter is ideal shouldn't there be no aliasing in this case?

The sampling rate is 200Hz, the filter cutoff is 102.5Hz.  So the filter can pass frequencies at or above the Nyquist rate (specifically, exactly 100Hz).
Having an ideal filter isn't a sufficient condition to fully block potentially aliasing signals: you need any filter whose response is zero at and above Nyquist to block potentially aliasing signals.

So the expression given in the solution is wrong, right?

If you question is not "will an ideal filter with a cutoff above Nyquist satisfy anti-aliasing" but rather "did Oppenheimer put a 9 where they should have put a 10" then please edit your question to clarify what you're asking.  You asked about ideal filters and Nyquist -- not typos.
